# How to output in XML version and encoding (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

There is a plugin that forms an XML file for exporting goods. But no matter how hard I try, I can not insert the code `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>` at the beginning of the line. Unfortunately, it is necessary for the validation of the file. Now produces this way:

```
    <root>
<object>
<objectid></objectid>
<title></title>
<type></type>
...
</object>
<object>...</object>
...
</root>
```

I'm not a pro on this issue, but I will give only a piece of code in which the problem is possible:

```
public function onAjaxBTExport()
        {    
$xml = new SimpleXMLElementExtended('<root/>');
    ....
    $data = $xml->asXML();
    file_put_contents(JPATH_SITE.'/data.xml', $data);
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo  $data;
    die;
    }

    class SimpleXMLElementExtended extends SimpleXMLElement
       {
          private function addCDataToNode(SimpleXMLElement $node, $value = '')
          {
             if ($domElement = dom_import_simplexml($node))
             {
                $domOwner = $domElement->ownerDocument;
                $domElement->appendChild($domOwner->createCDATASection("{$value}"));
             }
          }
          public function addChildWithCData($name = '', $value = '')
          {
             $newChild = parent::addChild($name);
             if ($value) $this->addCDataToNode($newChild, "{$value}");
             return $newChild;
          }
          public function addCData($value = '')
          {
             $this->addCDataToNode($this, "{$value}");
          }
       }
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, it is necessary for the validation of the file" — It shouldn't be. Those are the defaults. The prolog is only required if you use non-default values for one or both of those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (the XML transformation language) using the [identity tranform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) template which copies entire document as is and then explicitly set the *omit-xml-declaration* to "no". The added benefit of this is pretty printing your output.

To run XSLT 1.0 in PHP, be sure to enable the [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) extension in .ini file. Below XSLT is embedded as string but can be parsed from file.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElementExtended('<root/>');
... 
$data = $xml->asXML();

// LOAD XML SOURCE
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($data);

// LOAD XSLT SOURCE
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML('<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
                  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
                  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

                  <!-- Identity Transform -->
                  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                     <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                     </xsl:copy>
                  </xsl:template>

               </xsl:transform>');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// ECHO TO CONSOLE
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $newXML;

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents(JPATH_SITE.'/data.xml', $newXML);
```